# Save pandas dataframe as txt file in Python, with dataframe columns containing either single int values or python lists

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, opencv

I am trying to save a complex pandas dataframe as txt file in Python.
The dataframe is composed of data obtained using openCV, with different characteristics of objects being detected using a computer vision code. For example, data present in the dataframe are object height, object width, class label, and contour coordinates (x and y coordinates) of the objects present in the image.

To help you visualize this, here is what the dataframe looks like:

|  | Height | Width | Label | Contour |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 32 | SpeciesA | [[[ 670 1921]] [[ 666 1925]] [[ 665 1924]] ... [[ 658 1870]]] |
| 2 | 15 | 30 | SpeciesB | [[[ 670 1921]] [[ 666 1925]] [[ 665 1924]] ... [[ 658 1870]]] |
| 3 | 11 | 31 | SpeciesC | [[[ 670 1921]] [[ 666 1925]] [[ 665 1924]] ... [[ 658 1870]]] |
| 4 | 10 | 27 | SpeciesD | [[[ 670 1921]] [[ 666 1925]] [[ 665 1924]] ... [[ 658 1870]]] |

My pandas dataframe is thus composed of Integers, Strings, and Lists, and this is where the trouble starts. How to properly save this as a txt so that I could later on load it again, and access each element of the dataframe?

I am asking this question because, in the past, before I started to add the contour lists to the dataframe, my code worked pretty fine, and was like this:

```
# Export dataframe as txt
df_to_save['Height'] = df_to_save['Height'].astype(int)
df_to_save['Width'] = df_to_save['Width'].astype(int)
df_to_save['Label'] = df_to_save['Label'].astype(str)
tfile = open("savedDF.txt", 'a')
tfile.write(df_to_save.to_string(index=False))
tfile.close()

# Load txt into pandas dataframe
df_loaded = pd.read_csv("savedDF.txt", sep=r'\s{1,}', engine='python')
```

So this worked fine, but now that I have added the contour list in a new column in my pandas dataframe, the export still works fine, but the import no longer works.

```
# Export dataframe as txt
df_to_save['Height'] = df_to_save['Height'].astype(int)
df_to_save['Width'] = df_to_save['Width'].astype(int)
df_to_save['Label'] = df_to_save['Label'].astype(str)
df_to_save['Contour'] = df_to_save['Contour'].astype(object)
tfile = open("savedDF.txt", 'a')
tfile.write(df_to_save.to_string(index=False))
tfile.close()

# Load txt into pandas dataframe
df_loaded = pd.read_csv("savedDF.txt", sep=r'\s{1,}', engine='python')
```

Indeed, this code generates this error:

**File "...python_parser.py", line 739, in _alert_malformed raise ParserError(msg)**

**pandas.errors.ParserError: Expected 88 fields in line 10, saw 95. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used**

I am therefore wondering what is the proper way to generate, export, and import such dataframe composed of multiple types of data (integer, str, and lists)? The idea is to be able to access each of the value contained in the table cell, but also to redraw object contours on the image etc., so I wish to preserve the list format, or at least a format that will allow me to generate again the object contours later on, when loading the saved txt file, using openCV drawContours function.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why can't you save as parquet?

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I tried following your comment but eventually ended up with the same issue given that parquet cannot handle multi arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a working solution for my issue. Problem with contours was the array structure more than an issue with a List format.

Here is my solution

**1. Storing contour X and Y coordinates**

First thing I do is to store as a List the X and Y coordinates of the contours of the objects I have in my images:

```
cntCoordX = [x[0][0] for x in cnt]
cntCoordY = [x[0][1] for x in cnt]
```

My pandas dataframe then looks like this:

|  | Height | Width | Label | XCoord | YCoord |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 32 | SpeciesA | [670 666 665 ... 658] | [1921 1925 1924 ... 1870] |
| 2 | 15 | 30 | SpeciesB | [670 666 665 ... 658] | [1921 1925 1924 ... 1870] |
| 3 | 11 | 31 | SpeciesC | [670 666 665 ... 658] | [1921 1925 1924 ... 1870] |
| 4 | 10 | 27 | SpeciesD | [670 666 665 ... 658] | [1921 1925 1924 ... 1870] |

**2. Saving dataframe as txt**

Dataframe is then saved as follows:

```
dataframe.to_csv("filename.txt", index = False, sep='\t')
```

**3. Later, reloading the txt file into a pandas dataframe and recalculating the contours**

And in the other module of my code, when willing to load this saved dataframe, here is the code for loading the dataframe and to create a new column that reconstructs the contours based on the X and Y coordinates:

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv("filename.txt", sep='\t', engine='python')
allContours = []

for i in range(len(dataframe)):
    contourXCoord = dataframe.loc[i, 'ContourXCoord']
    contourXCoord = contourXCoord.replace("[","")
    contourXCoord = contourXCoord.replace("]","")
    contourXCoord = contourXCoord.split(", ")
    contourXCoord = [int(x) for x in contourXCoord]
    contourYCoord = dataframe.loc[i, 'ContourYCoord']
    contourYCoord = contourYCoord.replace("[","")
    contourYCoord = contourYCoord.replace("]","")
    contourYCoord = contourYCoord.split(", ")
    contourYCoord = [int(y) for y in contourYCoord]

    contourCoords = []
    for i in range(len(contourXCoord)):
        contourCoord = [contourXCoord[i],contourYCoord[i]]
        contourCoords.append(contourCoord)

    contourCoordsArray = np.array(contourCoords).reshape((-1,1,2)).astype(np.int32)
    allContours.append(contourCoordsArray)

dataframe['Contours'] = allContours
```

Hoping this solution will help people facing the same issue as me.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment with a bunch of observations - but with more room.

First I've never been able to get the `df_to_save.to_string()` approach for creating an exact string representation of a dataframe to work.  Usually it is that the string representation is collapsed on a wide column.

Second writing out as a text file and then back in as a CSV presents some problems.  Before you write out the file the `Contour` is a single column. When you read it back in it becomes dozens of columns.  `read_csv` with `sep=r'\s{1,}'` means that every set of contiguous spaces in the original `Contour` field delineates a new field.  It would be possible to make that work but you would need perfect orchestration.  Plus, you need the number of space-sets to be exactly the same in each row of the `Contour` column.  This tripped you up and that is why you ended up with `... Expected 88 fields in line 10, saw 95 ...`

You may want to investigate other approaches.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This helped rethinking my whole approach on this, and I eventually came up with an alternative approach that fixed my issue (see my answer).

Comment: @Marc Sure!  Glad to help.